# spring properties file including xml entities

Tags: xml, spring

I want to import properties file to spring config,and the value in the properties file has some xml entities,like <(<)>(>).
i done those tests,

1. do not reference those xml entities value,it's work.
2. reference those xml entities value,two format of value,not work.

   password=xxx<>-163

   password=xxx<>-163

Answer (score 0):

Put the password property value in the properties file with in CDATA tag.

Just like `password=<![CDATA[xxx<>-163]]>`

It will work properly.

Comment: but i got the answer,i use username as key in properties file,username is system default key.